# ALFA AWUS036NHV - Monitor Mode

Tags: kali-linux

I have recently come into ownership of the above product and was wondering if it is possible to enable monitor mode on said device? I figured this community might have a definite answer, if not a clever work around.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently As of December 2014, the common driver for this device does not support monitor mode on Linux. Kernel.org showed that monitor mode was untested however I did find this link https://wikidevi.com/wiki/ALFA_Network_AWUS036NHV

Answer (score 0):

I have the 36NH moddel, but to check; load up Kali Linux or what you prefer and open a Terminal. Type: "airmon-ng" this will list the available wireless interfaces. It should be on WLAN1. If it is type: "airmon-ng start wlan1" it should say monitor mode enabled on mon0 (WLAN1)

Answer (score 0):

Fix to patch the WLAN driver for AWUS036:

```
ifconfig wlan0 down 
rmmod r8187 rtl8187 2>/dev/null
wget http://dl.aircrack-ng.org/drivers/rtl8187_linux_26.1010.zip
unzip rtl8187_linux_26.1010.zip
cd rtl8187_linux_26.1010.0622.2006/
wget http://patches.aircrack-ng.org/rtl8187_2.6.27.patch
wget http://patches.aircrack-ng.org/rtl8187_2.6.32.patch
tar xzf drv.tar.gz
tar xzf stack.tar.gz
patch -Np1 -i rtl8187_2.6.27.patch
patch -Np1 -i rtl8187_2.6.32.patch
make
make install
```